# List Comprehension in Python Programming

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> numbers = [34.6, -203.4, 44.9, 68.3, -12.2, 44.6, 12.7]
>>> newlist = []
>>> newlist = [newlist.append(number) for number in numbers if number > 0]
>>> newlist
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

The **newlist** list variable should contain all the positive values from the above list **numbers**. I do not seem to get the correct answer. Can anybody please point out the mistake in the above code? I've just now started learning python. I'm using python 3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do

```
newlist = [number for number in numbers if number > 0]
```

which gives you the values in `newlist`

The reason you get `[None, None, None, None, None]` is because, the return type of `newlist.append(number)` is `None` which is being appended to the list comprehension while traversing through the individual elements.

Demo:

```
>>> a = []
>>> x = a.append(1)
>>> print x
None
>>>
```

So, the fix is:

```
>>> numbers = [34.6, -203.4, 44.9, 68.3, -12.2, 44.6, 12.7]
>>> newlist = [number for number in numbers if number > 0]
>>> newlist
[34.6, 44.9, 68.3, 44.6, 12.7]
>>>
```

Comment: That works. I did not know that append returns None. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped. The Python interpreter is a good place to try out things. Some concepts might not be very evident from the documentation.

Comment: That's true. Some concepts are really easy but the way it has been presented in the documentation is just not very comprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

`list.append()` returns a `None`, so the output that you are getting is expected. Here's how you can do list comprehension in your case.

```
newlist = [i for i in numbers if i > 0]
```